# Body background switcher with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm making a webpage that needs to switch between background images on a page, where the user can click on back and forth arrows to sift through each background while browsing.

For each background there needs to be a dynamic description for each image.

For example, the user may load the page and see the body background with a description for what it is, and then click on the right arrow and the background changes, along with the description for the new background.

Does anyone know of a way to implement this, or know of a plug in that already does it?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Tools, probably [Tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/slideshow.html).

Easy to set up, lightweight, encourages good HTML, and completely customizable via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [Supersized](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)?

Seems to be exactly what you are -were- looking for!